# Password valid for a period FOS user Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOS user bundle in my project, I have a functional specification : I need when I create a user his password have to be valid for some days : example 2 days. I searched and I didn't find how to make it. Any one have an idea which can help ? thanks

Comment: Add a custom field to your user entity called 'pwd_valid_until', at password creation/change time you should set the 'pwd_valid_until' field to the expiration date(i.e. 2 days in your case) and at authentication time, check that 'pwd_valid_until' is later than the date of today.

Comment: it seems that this is the way to revolve that, but to wich date we should compare the pwd_valid_until. if pwd_valid_until contains 2 days it will contain 2 days tomorrow and after tomorrow too

Comment: You should perform something like creating 'new DateTime()' which will be instanciated as today without arguments. Then you'll use a 'DateInterval('P2d')' that you'll add to the created DateTime. You'll store the addition in the 'pwd_valid_until' row.